# Aes_decrypt on varchar column?

Tags: mysql, encryption

I made a small form for a website which stored the formdata with Aes_encrypt. The database that was used accidentally set the column type to varchar, and the collation to utf-8. Now when I run aes_decrypt, I get null as a result. Is there any way to still decrypt the data? Or is it now completely useless?

Thanks!

Comment: Is the data truncated? Can the encrypted payload fit the column? If not, then what you have is useless. When you decrypt something and it fails, you always get the reason why. Since there's no code, you'll have to figure out how to get error message out of your code.

Comment: I think it can fit the column. The content is of one entry for example is JcXOomXShZ7d6 (with the column type being varchar(255) ). When I decrypt I don't get an error, I just get NULL as a value..